# How Flink encodes state data in CEP scenario?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql, flink-statefun

I am using Flink CEP to recognize some event patterns, the query looks like

```
select * from $TABLE
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
        partition by $PARTITION_FIELDS
        order by event_time
        measures
            ...
        one row per match
        after match SKIP past LAST ROW
        pattern(...) within interval '1' minute
        define
            ...
    )
```

I enabled RocksDB state backend. I would like to check what the state data look like in RocksDB. By using RocksDB's Java API, the state data was retrieved successfully, however they are encoded.

**I would like to know how and where Flink encodes those state data.**

Thanks

Comment: You might start your investigation by looking at https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.11/flink-libraries/flink-cep/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/cep/nfa/NFA.java and https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.11/flink-libraries/flink-cep/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/cep/operator/CepOperator.java.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for your reply. If I use FlinkCEP API directly, the generated query plan is also based on NFA and CepOperator?

Comment: The code I linked to is the low-level pattern matching engine in FlinkCEP. MATCH_RECOGNIZE is built on top of that.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks, David